# How to square an imaginary number in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, complex-numbers

I'm working with imaginary numbers in VBA and part of the math I'm trying to implement involved squaring imaginary numbers. Now I tried to square a complex number in the immediate window but got a "type mismatch run-time 13" error. Here is the code below.

```
? WorksheetFunction.Complex(k1, -1*rho*sigma*phi)
? (WorksheetFunction.Complex(k1, -1*rho*sigma*phi))^2
```

The second line is where I'm getting an error and I'm not sure how to square this complex number in VBA. Tried to look online as well but was unable to find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ImProduct` or `ImPower` worksheet functions.

```
Sub WorkingWithComplexNumbers()
  Dim vNum As Variant
  Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
  Set wf = WorksheetFunction
  
  vNum = wf.Complex(2, 3)
  
  Debug.Print wf.ImProduct(vNum, vNum)
  Debug.Print wf.ImPower(vNum, 2)
End Sub
```

If you type `WorksheetFunction.im` you will get a list of all functions you can use on a complex number.

Comment: Thank you. I know that I can do `wf.ImSum` for addition of two complex numbers, what if I want to subtract two complex numbers? Is there a function for that? Or should I just multiply one of the complex numbers by -1 and sum the two complex numbers like that?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way I know to subtract is to multiply by `-1` and then sum

Comment: @ameyashete Use `wf.ImSub()`. Somewhat esier ;-p)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ImProduct` worksheet function.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.improduct